# why is "cygboost_filesystem.dll missing" dialog box appearing?

Tags: c++, boost, dll, cygwin, codeblocks

I am using Cygwin to build and run my c++ projects and I debug using C::B (codeblocks).

Normally its no problem for me to first use my makefile in cygwin to build, then switch to C::B and debug my code, however now lately suddenly I get a dialog box:

saying that I am missing the cygboost_filesystem.dll file

- that is strange because the project can run in cygwin and when I rebuild inside C::B then it can also run there -- this is some new error - normally there is no problem first building in cygwin and then debugging in C::B

Can someone point me to what could be the cause of this missing .dll file message